# How do I crop Plotly image?

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I am currently working on flask app which use plotly express to render interactive image. I use javascript to track the shapes drawn by the user. I could get the coordinates using plotly js. How do I crop the image display ? Can I crop it in the frontend with javascript instead of doing it in the backend ?

Here are my code :

Javascript

```
var aoiCoordinates;
var aoiImage = document.getElementById('aoi-image-container');
aoiImage.on('plotly_relayout', (eventData) => {
    if (eventData.hasOwnProperty('shapes')) {
        var shapes = eventData.shapes;
        aoiCoordinates = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
            var x0 = parseInt(shapes[i].x0);
            var x1 = parseInt(shapes[i].x1);
            var y0 = parseInt(shapes[i].y0);
            var y1 = parseInt(shapes[i].y1);
        }
    }

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-9" id="aoi-image-container" style="display: none;">
   <div class="card-auto d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <h3 class="text-center mb-3">Area of Interest</h3>
    <div class="card-body text-center" id="aoi-image" style="max-width: 100%;">
     <div id="aoi-container">
        {{ aoi_html | safe }}
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Python Flask

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def process_image():
    if not session.get("logged_in"):
        return redirect("/login")
    if request.method == "POST":
        img = cv2.imread(UNINFERENCED_IMAGE_FILE_PATH)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        fig = px.imshow(img)

        fig.update_layout(
                    width=950,
                    height=850,
                    margin=dict(l=7, r=7, t=0, b=0),
                    xaxis=dict(visible=False),
                    yaxis=dict(visible=False),
                    template="plotly_dark",
                )

        aoi_html = fig.to_html(
                    config={
                        "modeBarButtonsToAdd": [
                            "drawrect",
                            "eraseshape",
                        ]
                    },
                    div_id="aoi-container")


       return render_template(
                    "correct_detections_form_template.html",
                    image_info=image_info,
                    class_options=class_options,
                    info_message="Kindly Select Classes To Perform Inferencing!",
                    aoi_html=aoi_html
                )
```

My only known approach is to rewrite the image on backend.